# run two different python programs and sync they variables

Tags: python, server

I need to run two different python programs in two different places (two droplets in Digital Ocean for example), I need to share some variables between them, and I don't really know the best way to accomplish that.

Any idea or advice will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the rate at which you update and use them permits and if there's no overlap, I'd store each variable in an high availability database and read them from there.